# I believe i may have somehow bricked by computer. Ubuntu was acting strangley and now will not boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04
I can give you a hardware list if you need it.

So i was trying to see if  i could setup cryptocurrencey mining to run on my primary pc just to test some stuff.
I was following [this guide](https://linuxhandbook.com/nicehash-linux/) to try and run nicehash on my Linux machine.
I recall i spent a bit of time experimenting with it because of some python dependency issues (there is this package called wx kept not working) and completely removed and reinstalled python at least once, though i don't think that should matter.

At any rate eventually i gave up and just ran the command line version and after that Ubuntu would not open the terminal or show it from the programs screen
I rebooted and now it is stuck showing the motherboard manufacturer logo screen.

I can plug the boot sdd into my laptop with a usb and it is working fine so i dont believe it is a hardware issue.

I also followed [This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on running boot repair which failed and spat out [This error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yrGn8h2Xbw/)